# Adding Bottom Padding to last visible element with div with overflow-y property

Tags: html, css, padding

I am working on a div which contains a list which overflows with the overflow-y property set to "scroll". I'm trying to add padding to the bottom of what's visible within the scroll area such that the last visible list item in the div has bottom padding, but the padding is only applied at the end of the entire list itself after scrolling is complete, instead of the last currently visible list item. How can I add padding to the last currently visible list item in the div?

```
Expectation: 
_____________
| * item 1   |  
| * item 2   |
| * item 3   |
|____________| <-- extra padding beyond last visible element (remaining list items 
cannot be seen until you scroll lower)

Actual:
_____________
| * item 1   |  
| * item 2   |
| * item 3   |
|_* item 4 __| <-- extra padding is only added at the end of the entire 
scrolled list
```

Code: https://codepen.io/afreymiller/pen/BYVByy

Comment: Hey Adam, have you try target it with `:last-child` with css?. You can do so by doing like this `li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Having a second look at the question...last visible `<li>` doesn't make much sense, but last `<li>` (which is always the bottom of the `<ul>`) does. Are you trying to ensure that none of the `<li>` are partially obscured no matter where the `<ul>` has scrolled to?

Answer (score 1):

As TNG commented below the original answer does not answer the question. The following update does. To recap the OP question:

> *"How can I add padding to the last currently visible list item in the div?"*

So this implies that the visible portion of the list varies in height. To change the styles based on it's visibility and/or scroll position requires JavaScript/jQuery. The following demo is a pure CSS/HTML solution that uses `position`, `z-index`, an `<frame>`, and a sibling `<div>`.

The `<iframe>` has [`srcdoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes) attribute with the `<ul>` as it's value. The `<iframe>` (`.list`) and the container (`.box`) should have the same height.

### Demo

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow:hidden
}

.list {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  background: #fff;
}
  
.show { 
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.tall {
  height:125px
}
```

```html
<p>.mask is outlined to show it's location</p>
<section class='box'>
<iframe class='list' srcdoc='<ul style="height: 105px;padding:0px 0 45px 0"><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Pizza</li>  <li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Spinach</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Lettuce</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Burito</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Spaghetti</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Meatballs</li></ul>' scrolling='yes'></iframe>
<div class='mask show'>&nbsp;</div>
</section>
<p>.mask not outlined</p>
<section class='box'>
<iframe class='list' srcdoc='<ul style="height: 105px;padding:0px 0 45px 0"><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Pizza</li>  <li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Spinach</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Lettuce</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Pepper</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Spaghetti</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Meatballs</li></ul>' scrolling='yes'></iframe>
<div class='mask'>&nbsp;</div>
</section>
<p>.box, and .list height increases</p>
<section class='box tall'>
<iframe class='list tall' srcdoc='<ul style="height: 105px;padding:0px 0 45px 0"><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Pizza</li>  <li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Spinach</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Lettuce</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Liver</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Spaghetti</li><li style="height: 20px;padding-bottom: 5px">Meatballs</li></ul>' scrolling='yes'></iframe>
<div class='mask'>&nbsp;</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer OP's question, In this solution padding appears after last item on the list (Meatballs).The question was about padding after last item that is not hidden by oveflow. In the example above if you reduce container height so that only 3 items fit there, ther should be padding after Lettuce